# How to export int to "txt" file and then at a later date be able to import them back as int 's

Tags: python

Exporting the data:

```
num = 0

exportData = open("results_file.txt", "a")


while num < len(runs) - 1:
    exportData.write(str(runs[num]) + "\n")
    num = num + 1

exportData.close()
```

Importing the data into the new file:

```
runs = []

num = 1

count = len(open("results_file.txt").readlines(  ))
print(count)

importData = open("results_file.txt", "r")
while num < count:
    runs.append(importData.read(num))
    print(importData.read(num))
    num = num + 1
importData.close()
```

My goal is to export the array of integers to a file (can be something else than a txt file for all I care) and then to import them at a later date into a new file and use them there as integers (performing mathematical operations on them)

The error that I'm getting (on line 28 I'm trying to use the first number in the array for a mathematical calculation):
line 28, in  if runs[num] < 7: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

```
runs = []

num = 1

count = len(open("results_file.txt").readlines(  ))
print(count)

importData = open("results_file.txt", "r")
while num < count:
    runs.append(int(importData.read(num)))
    print(importData.read(num))
    num = num + 1
importData.close()
```

Adding int() returns this error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4\n1'

Comment: You should be getting an error in your second script around `num = num + 1` which should give you a workable amount of information; are you getting an error there?

Comment: Just a recommendation - usually, if you're working with files you'll want to use a with statement:
with open("filename") as my_file:
    #do stuff with my_file

This makes sure that if there are any unhandled exceptions/other errors, the file still gets closed properly.

Comment: @The_Moth can you update your question to include that error? Formatting in the comments makes it looks much less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not being pythonic, and many of the answers here aren't either.  So, let me clean up your code a bit.

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("results_file.txt", "a") as exportData:
    for run in runs:
        exportData.write(str(run) + "\n")

runs = []
with open("results_file.txt", "r") as importData:
    runs.extend([literal_eval(x) for x in importData])
```

I'll break this down line by line:

`from ast import literal_eval` is the safest way to parse things that are strings into python objects.  It's better than using a plain old `eval` because it won't run arbitrary code.  We'll use this function to read the data latter.

`with open(...) as ...` is the best way to open a file.  It contains the file-object within a single scope and catches errors.  Look this one up here: [Pep 343](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html)

`for ... in ...` For loops that you're using are not pythonoic at all.  The pythonic way is to use iterators no need to count lines and declare variables to keep track... the python objects keep track of themselves.  (If you need a counter I highly recommend that you look up `enumerate()` [Enumerate() in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/)

`exportData.write(str(run) + "\n")` only change here is that with the pythonic `for` loop there's no need to index the `runs` list anymore.

`runs = []`  I think you know what this is, but I have to declare it out of the `with` statement because if the `with` statement throws an error, and you were to catch it, `runs` will be initialized.

I've already discussed `with` statements.

`runs.extend([literal_eval(x) for x in importData])` Has two things going on.  `extend` appends a list to a list... cool.  The more interesting part here is the list comprehension. [Here's a tutorial on list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).  As soon as you get comfortable with the `for` loops, the list comprehension is the next pythonic step.  For further pythonic enlightenment, this line could also be replaced with: `runs.extend(map(literal_eval, importData))`

That's it, 9 lines.  Happy hacking.

Comment: WOW! Thx alot. That is really cool, to see how much that code can be simplified. I hope I'll one day reach a level of pythonic enlightenment similar to yours. And again thanks.

Comment: `python -c 'import this'`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are experiencing is most likely due to the fact you're trying to add a string to an integer. Try doing

```
runs = []

num = 1

count = len(open("results_file.txt").readlines(  ))
print(count)

importData = open("results_file.txt", "r")
while num < count:
    runs.append(int(importData.read(num)))
    print(importData.read(num))
    num = num + 1
importData.close()
```

Comment: this did not solve the problem :( I added the new error messge I recieve to the post.

Answer (score 0):

The main function/tool you're looking for is `int()`. For example:

```
>>> int('15')
15

>>> int('15') + 5
20
```

But you also can save yourself some real headaches by coding this differently. For example, you do not need to know the number of lines ahead of time. You can just call `.readline()` until it returns an empty string. Or even iterate over the file and when it ends, it with exit.

Another tip, and this is just good practice, is to use the context manager for opening files. So instead of

```py
file = open('myfile.txt')
for line in file:
    print(line)
```

you would do:

```py
with open('myfile.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

The big advantage of the latter is that if will *always* make sure `file` is closed properly. This is especially helpful when *writing* to a file.

Comment: thx for the feedback with the with function and the line reading one, but adding int() did not solve the problem I am having.